# Javascript smooth scrolling to anchors on other pages

Tags: javascript, scroll

I'm trying to implement a smooth scrolling effect using javascript for anchors in a main menu. The links in the menu look like `<a href="/#target">`.

This code works fine when clicking on the links on the same page as the anchors:

```
    Object.entries(document.querySelectorAll('[href*="#"]'))
    .forEach(([ index, node ]) => {
        node.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                const target = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('href').replace('/','');
            event.preventDefault();

            window.scrollTo({
                top: document.querySelector(target).getBoundingClientRect().top - 50,
                behavior: 'smooth'
            });
        });
    });
```

but not when clicking from another page. From the other page, it jumps directly to the anchor for one of the links, and for another further down the page, it's a few 100 pixels too high.

I can't use `scroll-behavior: smooth` either because the page also has other javascript carousels on it, and there seems to be a [bug relating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73055175/772437) to Chromium and `requestAnimationFrame`.

Edit: updated code based on Brad's suggestion.

```
const scrollToTarget = (target) => {
    window.scrollTo({
        top: document.querySelector(target).getBoundingClientRect().top - 50,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });
}

const scrollTo = (target) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const home = document.querySelector('.page-home');
    if (home) {
        scrollToTarget(target)
    } else {
        window.location.href = '/';
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            setTimeout(scrollToTarget(target), 2000);
        });
    }
}

const link1 = document.querySelector('.link-1');
const link2 = document.querySelector('.link-2');

link1.addEventListener('click', (event) => { scrollTo('#one'); });
link2.addEventListener('click', (event) => { scrollTo('#two'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible directly, as there isn't really a solid context between Page A and Page B.

At best, you can remove all the actual anchors on the "receiving" Page B and then have your JavaScript scroll to the appropriate place once loaded.  This is a really bad practice however, in terms of usability.

Comment: leaving questions of usability aside (because without any js having links to anchors on one page from another page which don't actually scroll to the point on that page isn't great usability either) I've added some updated code based on your suggestion. But even with that, when clicking on the links from the other page, you get redirected to the receiving page but still get errors because `document.querySelector(...)` is null.

Comment: Sorry, realised I needed to wait for the document to be loaded before running the `scrollToTarget` (code updated), which makes the error go away, but no scrolling happens.

Comment: You'll have to load your JS as a module, or only run it when the DOM is ready, or there won't be any content on the page to scroll to.  In any case, what I was suggesting was on page load, checking `location.hash` and searching for a matching element (using an alternative attribute such as `data-scroll-to-id` or something), and then scrolling to it.

Comment: Sorry, not really following what that should look like.

Answer (score -1):

Create anchor tags with unique id attributes on the destination page. For example, if you want to scroll to a section with the id "section1" on the destination page, your anchor tag should look like this:

```
<a id="section1"></a>
```

```js
// Smooth scroll to anchor links
function smoothScrollToAnchor() {
  const links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]');
  links.forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const href = this.getAttribute('href');
      const target = document.querySelector(href);
      if (target) {
        const offsetTop = target.offsetTop;
        const scrollOptions = {
          top: offsetTop,
          behavior: 'smooth'
        };
        window.scrollTo(scrollOptions);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
Create anchor tags with unique id attributes on the destination page. For example, if you want to scroll to a section with the id "section1" on the destination page, your anchor tag should look like this:

<a id="section1"></a>
On the source page, create links or buttons that trigger the smooth scrolling to the anchors on the destination page. For example:

<a href="destination-page.html#section1">Scroll to Section 1</a>
Add the following JavaScript code to your source page. This code will handle the smooth scrolling behavior:
```